# How to copy first file to first host, second file to second host and so on via ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have 10 hosts and 10 files. I want to copy one of 10 files to corresponding host:

> 1_file.txt -> 1_host
>
> 2_file.txt -> 2_host
>
> ...
>
> 10_file.txt -> 10_host

I've tried to do it with zip filter, like

```
- name: Copy splitted files to instances
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.0 }}"
    dest: "{{ remote_ips_file }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ splitted_files.files | zip(instances) | list }}"
```

but got an error:

```
 {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Another way (from ChatGPT) was:

```
- name: Copy files to hosts
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to host
    copy:
      src: "{{ item.0 }}"
      dest: "/tmp/{{ item.1 }}"
    loop: "{{ zip(files, hosts) }}"

vars:
  files: ['/path/to/file1', '/path/to/file2']
  hosts: ['host1', 'host2']
```

But also got an error:

```
zip is undefined
```

How to do it with proper way?

**Edit**
I've found workaround, but it works not in parallel:

```
- name: Copy splitted files to instances
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.0.path }}"
    dest: "{{ remote_ips_file }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item.1 }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ splitted_files.files }}"
    - "{{groups['all']}}"
```

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. See the project below for an example of what *mre* means. It's not possible to post here questions like this.  Where does the variables *splitted_files, instances, remote_ips_file, ...* come from ? Does the list of the hosts come from the *groups* or from a variable? The iterations repeatedly running on all hosts are redundant. You have to provide the expected results. Shall the copied file be renamed to the name of the remote host? ... Your question will be closed if you keep it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the lists

```yaml
  my_files: [file1, file2]
  my_hosts: [host1, host2]
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  hosts_files: "{{ dict(my_hosts|zip(my_files)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hosts_files:
    host1: file1
    host2: file2
```

Use the dictionary in the task

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: "{{ hosts_files[inventory_hostname] }}"
        dest: /tmp
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

1 directory, 5 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
host1 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
host2 ansible_host=10.1.0.63

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: host1,host2

  vars:

    my_files: [file1, file2]
    my_hosts: [host1, host2]

    hosts_files: "{{ dict(my_hosts|zip(my_files)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hosts_files
      run_once: true

    - copy:
        src: "{{ hosts_files[inventory_hostname] }}"
        dest: /tmp
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [host1,host2] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  hosts_files:
    host1: file1
    host2: file2

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.61 ls -1 /tmp/file1
/tmp/file1
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.63 ls -1 /tmp/file2
/tmp/file2
```

Comment: thank you very much, approach with dictionary works well!